# Change the border color of fa-fa heart

Tags: html, css

how can I change the border color of fa -fa heart icon.

I want border color as white

```
<i class="fa fa-heart heart fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">
```

I want to change the exact heart border color to white to anyone please help me

Comment: u want filled heart with different border or just a custom color bordered heart without filled color??

Comment: .fa-heart{border: 1px solid #fff;} It will come in square

Comment: with filled color and heart border should be white exact only heart

Answer (score 2):

```css
body{
  background:#000;
}
.heart {
  color: #fff; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fa fa-heart-o heart fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">
```

Use `fa-heart-o` instead of `fa-heart` and then use css color property this way you can color border but it will be blank inside just a bordered heart.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hhhh {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.heart {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.heart1 {
    bottom: 1px;
    font-size: 28px;
    left: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: .heart class color #fff if any using color

Answer (score 0):

There are gererating icon using font-awesome font so we can't set border-color to any font-icon

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hhhh {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.heart {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.heart1 {
    bottom: 1px;
    font-size: 28px;
    left: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
    top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hhhh">
  <i class="fa fa-heart heart fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-heart heart1 fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```